# Simple page using tab and accordion from angular ui-bootstrap fails to load in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, internet-explorer-8, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a somewhat complex SPA working in Firefox and Chrome.  It fails without much information in IE8.  The full app uses ngTable and the tab and accordion components from ui-bootstrap, but I've been able to construct a skeleton version without ngTable, but still with ui-bootstrap, that still fails to do anything useful in IE8.

The resulting skeleton uses a single tab and a list of dynamic accordions, using data loaded from a stored json file.

When I run it i IE8, I just get the following in the console:

```
  [object Error]<div class="tab-pane ng-scope" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-class="{active: tab.active}" tab-content-transclude="tab">
  [object Error]
```

At this point, the page displays my title and the contents of the tab header, but without the tab enclosure, and without the contents of the tab.

I believe I've managed to produce a plunkr (this is my first plunkr, so please tell me if I'm doing something wrong) that corresponds to the app I'm loading in IE8 (plunkr not working in IE8 makes this even more annoying): http://plnkr.co/edit/Ak26Pj4FwTXJ7USQBvhj

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.  It's been pointed out to me that AngularJS ui-bootstrap doesn't support IE8.  They aren't deliberately avoiding it, they just don't have time to support IE8.  Sad situation.